# Unusual memory usage spike

Tags: firefox, memory, broadband

Ok, on Windows 7 64 bit, I basically use Firefox to browse the web, with a DSL broadband connection.
Sometimes while surfing, I see the computer slows to a crawl for a few minutes and then goes all right again. At this time the Task Manager shows 98% memory usage with 3.9 GB being used out of 4 GB ram.

Today when this happened, I ended the Firefox process, and the usage instantly reverted back to normal 600 MB.
So whats happening?

---

This is the paste of the firefox memory dump: @magicandre1981

http://pastebin.com/ifbSB6jc

Update: The problem may not be Firefox. Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image: spike]

Comment: Have you tried disabling add-ons? Please mention which version of firefox you are using, and also the add-ons.

Comment: @VenkatH Firefox 17.0.1 Addons: Adblock, Abduction, AVG plugin, Nitro PDF plugin, Shockwave plugin

Comment: Remove AVG, install MSE and see if that fixes it.

Comment: inside Firefox visit about:memory ,copy the output to http://pastebin.com/ and post a link here.

Comment: @Karan you think AVG is a problem? Now that you say, from time to time, AVG displays warning that firefox using too much memory.... <br>you think its related?

Comment: Yep, I think it could be a likely source. Why don't you give MSE a shot for some time and see if you get similar RAM usage spikes.

Comment: @Karan MSE is crap and the slowest tool you can use. He has Firefox issues and no AV issues. Without the about:memory output we can't help.

Comment: @magicandre1981 See edit above.

Comment: when you have the high Mem issue again, use RAMMap (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx) to see what is using the memory. If you're unsure, store it as RMP, zip the file and upload it.